# Scaling image using variables

Tags: javascript, html, image, variables, scale

Im trying to scale an image using variables rather than a set in stone scale. I know using "scale(0.5,0.5)" works but I want to do something like "scale(x,y)" so the scale factor changes depending on what variables x and y are, However when I try doing this, the image will no longer scale like it did when it had a set scale factor. How can I solve this? Thanks for any help. Here's an example of what I mean.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImg" src="img_pulpit.jpg">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
var a = document.getElementById("myImg");
var d = 5
var e = 10
var f = d/e
var g = 10
var h = 30
var i = g/h

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myImg").style.WebkitTransform = "scale(f, i)";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if it's an image...why don't you just use the background-image and background-size? would understand the scaling if it wasn't just an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myImg").style.WebkitTransform = "scale(" + f + "," + i + ")";
}
```

Comment: @DiskJunky he have to concatenate current values of 'f' and 'i' in the string, and not the 'f' and 'i' chars

Answer (score 2):

Just use string concatenation (`"scale(" + f + ", " + i + ")"`) or string interpolation (`` `scale(${f}, ${i})` ``).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use concat the value of f and i

```
document.getElementById("myImg").style.WebkitTransform = "scale("+f+","+i+")";
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<img id="myImg" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/gN6iBKP1b2GTXZZoCxhyXiYIAh8QJ_8xzlhEK6csyDadA4GdkEdIEy9Bc8s5jozt1g=w300">

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
var a = document.getElementById("myImg");
var d = 5
var e = 10
var f = d/e
var g = 10
var h = 30
var i = g/h

function myFunction() {
document.getElementById("myImg").style.WebkitTransform = "scale("+f+","+i+")";
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```